# Any Subscription require for using Full Office 365 API?

Tags: office365, office365api

I'm currently developing Web Site (C#.Net) that use Office 365 api to retrieve mail(Send also) and access Contacts from user's office365 mail/work accounts.
Now I'm stuck between 3 things (or may be 3 different apis).

1. Microsoft Office API
2. Microsoft Graph API. (may be 1 and 2 same).
3. Microsoft Discovery API.

I want to know about which API i should use, and Are there services fee or its free?
How To register site for development purpose as well as live environment?

Answer (score 2):

To use these APIs, you have to pay for the O365 service. You have to pay no royalties to use the APIs as a developer, but you have to buy at least one office 365 license to be able to test; and we found that for some tests even five or fifty Office 365 accounts are not enough.

1. Office 365 API can get/send mail and retrieve company directory as well as personal contact information.
2. Graph API will provide you the information from the company directory, and possibly also personal contacts. IIRC Graph API is a subset of the Office 365 API.
3. Discovery API does not help you at all.
4. EWS Managed API can help you to get/send mail and retrieve personal Outlook contacts, with both Office 365 and on-premise Exchange installations.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question,
After look into my account I found that I have "Exchange Online (Plan 1)" Subscriptions Plan for Office 365.
Is that(subscription) satisfy to retrive/send requests that I'm using?